# Show a toast notification when UWP app is being uninstalled

Tags: winapi, uwp

I want to find a solution when the user uninstalls my app, a toast notification will be shown. But I could not find any solution for it. I tried using, the package uninstall event:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.packagecatalog.packageuninstalling?view=winrt-18362
But this only worked when the app was opened. Not when the app is closed. Is there any way to observe app uninstallation? I heard I can do that using win32 API but not sure how. Can you guys help me? If you can suggest any win32 API that will also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You maybe able to use the [desktop6:UninstallAction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-desktop6-uninstallaction) package extension, which requires the customInstallActions restricted capability. You specify an executable in your package, a name for the action, and arguments to pass to the executable. Have the executable when invoked with the arguments display the desired toast notification.